# Input formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm using an `input type="number"`to allow users to put a duration time on a post. The format is `days hours:minutes:seconds` as the backend provides the format.

What I need to do is to give that format to the input. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use input type text with pattern:

```html
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="^\d{1,3} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$" placeholder="days hours:minutes:seconds"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

It will validate the text using 1-3 digits for days and 1-2 for hours minutes and seconds.

You can also restrict typing of no digits and colons and space using jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('input').keydown(function(e) {
        console.log(e.which);
        if (!((e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || (e.which == 186 && e.shiftKey) || e.which == 32)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^\d{1,3} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}$" placeholder="days hours:minutes:seconds"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `jQuery`, then take a look at:

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

you can use also

```
<input type="datetime">
```